# ffmpeg: When creating a slice of an audio file, how do i also copy over all the meta data from the original file?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

That's my question :)

the command i'm using is below

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:00:45 -acodec copy -i original.mp3 new_file.mp3
```

Thanks for any help!!

*EDIT:*
**Solution**

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:00:45 -map_meta_data new_track.mp3:original.mp3 -acodec copy -i original.mp3 new_track.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself, but this option looks like it may do what you want:

```
-map_meta_data new_file.mp3:original.mp3
```

You may get a better answer over at superuser.com.  This isn't really the right forum for your question.

Comment: Great! that worked. Though it didn't copy over the artist name. Strange.

Thanks though!